# mobile safari ignoring navigator.geolocation?

Tags: iphone, geolocation, mobile-safari

I have a simple call to:

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position){ etc. });
```

It works fine in desktop browser and Android phone. Testing on a brand new iPhone 5 (iOS6.1.3), mobile safari seems to ignore this call. It doesn't prompt for location permission. I've set it up in Web Inspector on my MacBook and break right on the call. It hits getCurrentPosition() and nothing happens.

Tested the phone on google maps web site and it does prompt me for location permission.

I must be doing something very stupid ...

Answer (score 1):

The problem was not having set `timeout` for the `getCurrentPosition` call. Leaving undefined, mobile safari kept timing out. The stupid part is that I didn't see this because I hadn't refreshed the web inspector and so was not seeing any console logs.